# ROS with QtCreator: autocompletion

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator, ros, catkin

I'm using and like QtCreator to code and build my ROS projects written in *c++*.

Unfortunately the **auto-completion for my own header files** is not working: e.g. `#include "LineTracker.hh"`

Building the project works perfectly. And also the auto-completion for other external packages like ros or opencv is working.

**Update 2.0:** With QtCreator 3.6 the solution is not working

**Update 1.0:** Found a solution, see bottom!

Thats how my CMakeLists.txt looks:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(line_tracking)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  tf
  sensor_msgs
  image_transport
  cv_bridge
)

catkin_package()


include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
)


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    src/line_tracking.cpp
    src/EDLineDetector.cpp
    src/LineTracker.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

# --- QT CREATOR STUFF ---

#Add all files in subdirectories of the project in
# a dummy_target so qtcreator has access to all files
FILE(GLOB children ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/*)
FOREACH(child ${children})
  IF(IS_DIRECTORY ${child})
    file(GLOB_RECURSE dir_files "${child}/*")
    LIST(APPEND extra_files ${dir_files})
  ENDIF()
ENDFOREACH()
add_custom_target(dummy_${PROJECT_NAME} SOURCES ${extra_files})
#
```

The file/package structure looks standard like this:

```
CMakeLists.txt
 |
 + -- src
 |
 + -- include
```

How do I have to adapt my CMakeLists.txt that QtCreator finds my headers for autocompletion?

Thank you very much for your help!

*Sidenote:*

When I use the top CMakeLists.txt file of the catkin workspace in QtCeator and I include the  header files under their package path like this: `#include <packageName/include/headerFile.h>` the auto-completion is working but the build is not working anymore. So this is only a bad and not userfriendly hack to get auto-completion during coding.

---

**Update 1.0:**

I found a solution which is working:

I *create a library from all the (class) files which have header files*, and link the library to the main file, instead of adding the files as executables. I posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34914661/2241356) as answer.

But I don't know why it is working like this and not without the way over the library. Any explanations?

---

**Update 2.0:**
I just upgraded to `QtCreator 3.6` and there my solution with the library in not working anymore.

Does anybody know another solution?!

Comment: Try to add  ${roscpp_INCLUDE_DIRS} to the include_directories command. Moreover, do you run qtcreator from command line after sourcing the setup files of both ros and you workspace? 
You might also need to add   ${roscpp_LIBRARIES} to the target_link_library command as well

Comment: I tried it but didn't help. `${roscpp_INCLUDE_DIRS}` points to the same (and less) directories as  `${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}`. And these are ROS specific directories, where auto-completion is working. I'm running QtCreator from command line.

Comment: did you run the cmake from qtcreator after importing the project?

Comment: Yes I did! But now I found a solution. See my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** This solution does NOT work with QtCreator 3.6

---

I found a solution to my own question. Not so much fun, but anyway, I spent a lot of time with that issue so here the solution, which is hopefully useful for others:

**Auto-completion with CMakeLists.txt in QtCreator 3.5.1 for your own classes**:

1. Create a library with all your classes: `ADD_LIBRARY(myFilesLib src/class1.cpp ...)`
2. Add your executable (main function): `add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)`
3. Link your library to your executable: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} myFilesLib)`

With this way over the library, auto-completion is working in QtCreator!

For ROS (catkin) don't forget to link the `${catkin_LIBRARIES}`.

Here the whole CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(example_project)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
)

catkin_package()

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

# Create a library with all your classes
add_library(myFilesLib
    src/class1.cpp
    src/class2.cpp
    src/class3.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(myFilesLib
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

# add your executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    src/main.cpp
)

# link the library with your classes to the executable
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  myFilesLib
)
```

I don't know why it is working only with the way over the library but it is working. Maybe somebody has an explanation?!

Answer (score 1):

This is really annoying. Finally I figured out a solution, that works at Qt Creator 4.1.0, and probably works at other versions.

1. Write your `include_directories` correctly, so that compilation is OK.
2. Below the `include_directories`, add the following line. Note that the sequence matters, the following line must locate below the `include_directories`.

   ```
   file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS */*.hpp */*.h)
   ```
3. Add `${HEADERS} # for qtcreator...` in one of your `add_executable`. like:

   ```
   add_executable(slam_pp_node
     ${HEADERS} # for qtcreator...
     src/***.cpp
   )
   ```
4. The above should be enough to solve the autocompletion problem. If not, add the following lines at the end of your CMakeList.txt:

   ```
   file(GLOB_RECURSE EXTRA_FILES */*)
   add_custom_target(${PROJECT_NAME}_OTHER_FILES ALL WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} SOURCES ${EXTRA_FILES})
   ```

Good luck!